# convert csv File to GML using python or other suggestions

Tags: python, networking, graph, tree, powerbi

I have a dataset containing network data of called calling columns consisting of two columns representing the connections between the two columns.

The dataset can be accessed from : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dViBlP1TP3qFLn6XFWPfsH4R0Y7VVIns/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=111642513965282802880&rtpof=true&sd=true

Since I'm using igraph in Python I would like to convert this file to GML format to use it here :
https://live.yworks.com/demos/layout/layoutstyles/index.html
Is there any way to do this?

As response to the person who wanna see what I tried :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdjVt.png)
I used the yworks proposition

Comment: Could you add what have you been trying?

Comment: Links are not appropriate in questions rather try to reproduce the goal u need to achieve by recreating tables and images with smaller exxample.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To convert an edge list file (.edges) to a gml file, try the code given below.
I have used the networkx package.

```
import networkx as nx
G= nx.read_edgelist('414.edges') # load your edgelist file
nx.write_gml(G, "414.gml")   # gml file will be created
```

For more info, visit https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/gml.html#module-networkx.readwrite.gml